# When Radio button is clicked a variable changes to another variable

Tags: jquery, variables, onclick, radio-button

I have a simple 2 option radio button.  I would think my code would work and have tried many other versions, but I am just missing something.  I need to get the var typeOfCards to change when radio button changes.  The variable is used in a later equation.

input value 155 checked should change typeOfCards to equal boxCards and
input value 145 checked should change typeOfCards to equal singleCards

```
<input name="SELECT___CD-0035___33" value="155" onclick="change_option('SELECT___CD-0035___33',this.value)" type="radio">Box Cards (Sold in Multiples of 3) <br>
<input checked="checked" name="SELECT___CD-0035___33" value="154" onclick="change_option('SELECT___CD-0035___33',this.value)" type="radio"> Single Cards (Sold in sets of 12 Cards/12 Envelopes)<br>

var singleCards = 12
var boxCards = 3
var typeOfCards = singleCards
$("input[value='155']").click(function() {
    typeOfCards = boxCards;
});
$("input[value='154']").click(function() {
    typeOfCards = singleCards;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the handlers aren't getting attached because they aren't inside document.ready and the script is running before the elements are created.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var singleCards = 12
var boxCards = 3
var typeOfCards = singleCards
$("input[value='155']").click(function() {
    typeOfCards = boxCards;
});
$("input[value='154']").click(function() {
    typeOfCards = singleCards;
});
});
```

btw, if you have the jQuery click handlers, you probably don't also want an onclick.

Check it, it works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccross59/4K2R7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have 'onclick' specified for the radio buttons.

Try this:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var singleCards = 12
        var boxCards = 3
        var typeOfCards = singleCards
        $(".radioSelect").click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "155")
                typeOfCards = boxCards;
            else
                typeOfCards = singleCards;
            alert(typeOfCards);
        });
    });
   </script>

<input name="SELECT___CD-0035___33" value="155" class="radioSelect" type="radio" />Box Cards (Sold in Multiples of 3) <br/>
<input checked="checked" name="SELECT___CD-0035___33" value="154" class="radioSelect" type="radio" /> Single Cards (Sold in sets of 12 Cards/12 Envelopes)<br/>
```